# Set NSWindow location/size on launch and Lion fullscreen resume = bad layout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fullscreen, osx-lion

I've created an application which initially stores and restores window size and location in the app delegate's `applicationWillFinishLaunching:` or `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Later I have replaces it with calling `[NSWindow setFrameUsingName:]` and such to store and load window location and size.

Both storing and loading works just fine (*with custom code and with setFrameUsingName*)

But now the problem: when I have enabled Fullscreen mode on the application and logout with the option "*restore windows*". It will launch the application in the separate window to become fullscreen but then my code is called again to set the window `size:` in effect displaying a small window in the big fullscreen screen.

It seems the lifecycle almost ends with the `windowDidEnterFullScreen:` call.
The `applicationWillFinishLaunching:` is called way before the window is put in full screen and the `NSWindow`'s styleMask doesn't show fullscreen there yet.

Anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems where caused by an fade-in animation during application launch.
Make sure you don't start animation on the window in applicationWillFinishLaunching in the app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a flag in `windowWillEnterFullScreen` to let your window know not to set its size.